# Depth camera not calibrated when using from pyrealsense

Tags: python, parameters, camera, calibration, realsense

The D455 intel camera shows pictures of different quality (not resolution) when depthmaps taken from the viewer vs standard python code. May be something with calibration parameters?

Used this code https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/3558 to set on the autoexposure. Helped a bit, but I still observe minor difference.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)